# Limit text selection area

Tags: html, css, selection

On, for example, GitHub, if you select code it only selects the code not the line numbers next to it:

[image: Text selection limit]

This is because they use a table - the line numbers in a `td` and the code in a `td`.

How can I achieve this with a `div`?

EDIT: Please see [www.duncannz.com](http://www.duncannz.com) and try to highlight text. I want the selection thing to only be inside the content area, not to fill the width of the page (eg selection background doesn't go past the black border)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gfp28/

```
<div>

  <ul class='no_select'>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
      <li>111111111</li>
      <li>222222222</li>
      <li>333333333</li>
      <li>444444444</li>
      <li>555555555</li>
  </ul>

</div>​
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: inline; 
  float: left; 
  margin: 10px;
}

.no_select { 
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
```

If you add this to your css, it should restrict the highlighting to the width of the container:

```
#actualcontent, #actualcontent * { position: relative; }
```

Comment: I do want text selection, but I want to limit it, as shown in the example picture.

Comment: Ah, OK. So if I only want one div on my page to be selectable, do I put that "no user select" code on `*` and then user-select: text on that div?

Comment: Yep, that is definitely one way you could go about it!

Comment: To answer my question: yes, but it still doesn't behave how I wanted, and how it does at GitHub. Will update question.

Comment: What if there are multiple selectable elements, which should be selected separately? http://jsfiddle.net/gfp28/12/

Comment: @AlexanderShutov Interesting use-case... Not sure off the top of my head. A JS solution would be possible with a library like Rangy. https://github.com/timdown/rangy You could write your own event handlers so that only one UL or element class can be highlighted at a time.